# Problems with React-Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

So basically, I have a problem with react router not rendering my SystemSidebar. I want to scroll through my  SystemSidebar components, but my problem is when I press on 'LinkSoundIcon' it redirects me to 'a new page' but that page doesnt render my systemSidebar . I want when I press on any of the links of my sidebar that my sidebar remains

```js
import React from 'react'
import './SystemSidebar.css'
import SoundIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Computer';
import ComputerIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Computer';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Sound from './Sound';
import Computer from './Computer;
const SystemSidebar=()=> {
  return (
    <div className='system'>
      <div className="sidebar">
        <Link to='Sound'><VolumeUpIcon /></Link>
        <h4> Sound</h4>   
        <Link to='Computer'><ComputerIcon /></Link>
        <h4> Computer</h4>   
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

import React,{Component} from 'react'
import Sound from './Sound';
import Computer from './Computer';
import SystemSidebar from './SystemSidebar';
class MainSystem extends Component {
  render(){
    return (
      <div className="MAIN">
        <BrowserRouter>
          <SystemSidebar />
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={SystemSidebar} />
            <Route exact path="/Sound" component={Sound}/>
            <Route exact path="/Computer" component={Computer}/>
          </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
    
export default MainSystem;
```

Comment: It looks like you've copy/pasted two components together here, so I'll speak mostly about the 2nd/bottom one. I am really confused by your component tree. You've got a `SystemSidebar` component inside the `BrowserRouter` but with no closing tag. Then you've also got a route inside the switch that also renders the `SystemSidebar` when the path is "/" exactly?

Comment: SystemSideBar closing tag was my typo.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so it seems a little wonky with your copy pasting (I hope this is just a problem that stems from copy and pasting and it's not like that in your code). But your Problem is here:

`<Route exact path="/Sound" component={Sound}/>`

You're saying here that the route should be EXACTLY `http://<your root uri>/Sound`

You should also use this exact route in the link if you want to hit it, this means you need to have the slash there:

`<Link to='/Sound'><VolumeUpIcon /></Link>`

Update:

So according to your comment you want the sidebar to stay when you click a link. In this case, take a look at your code:

```
<Switch>
  <Route exact path="/" component={SystemSidebar} />
  <Route exact path="/Sound" component={Sound}/>
  <Route exact path="/Computer" component={Computer}/>
</Switch>
```

You define here that the component `SystemSidebar` will only be loaded when you're at the Root directory ("/") of your App. It will be unloaded when you change that directory, for example, to "/Sound". `SystemSidebar` will be unloaded and `Sound` will be loaded instead.

Since your Sidebar should always be shown, it needs to be in your Main App and outside of your actual Router logic. Remember what the React Router does: It switches out components depending on which directory (which Sub-URL) you're in. It's best practice to have a Sidebar, an App Bar or similar things that are always there to be their own components. Your actual content should live in a separate container, where the needed component can be swapped out by the Router if need be. So something like this:

```
class MainSystem extends Component {
  render(){
    return (
      <div className="MAIN">
        <SystemSidebar />
        <div className="ContentContainer">
          <BrowserRouter>
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path="/Sound" component={Sound}/>
              <Route exact path="/Computer" component={Computer}/>
              {/* Route "/" should be last because it acts as fallback! */}
              <Route exact path="/" component={StartPage} />
            </Switch>
          </BrowserRouter>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

That's pretty basic but I hope you get the gist of it.

Also, I'd encourage you to take a look at an [UI framework like Material UI](https://material-ui.com/) for example. It already provides components ready for use (like your Sidebar which is called Drawer there), it's mobile first and easy to use with responsive design.

Comment: Did not work. but here are the screenshots.https://imgur.com/YjLmhLh https://imgur.com/1hwNlNr I want to scroll through my sidebar but when i click on the soundIcon in the sidebar I want to achieve that   sidebar stays but dashboard changes

Comment: @tekila12 I updated my answer based on your comment, hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

`<Link to='/Sound'><VolumeUpIcon /></Link>`
answer of your first problem and second if you want to access sidebar in each component then don't put it in switch route , simply put it outside the routing... or if u want to access it with specific route then try using nested routing